# iText7 Split Table inside Canvas - Exception Index out of range on Canvas.AddChild

Tags: c#, itext7

My table can have from 1 to 500 rows max, on first page there is room for about 27 rows, and for page >1 there is room for about 73 rows.
I´m using LayoutResult.GetSplitRenderer() and LayoutResult.GetOverflowRenderer().
Problem is when I use canvas.GetRenderer().AddChild() I got an Exception "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index".

I'm using last available iText 7.1.7 in .Net Core

Does anybody have some idea how can I make to work and get table splitted?
Just in case

```
public static MemoryStream MakePDF()
{
    MemoryStream zMS = new MemoryStream();
    PdfWriter writer1 = new PdfWriter(zMS);
    PdfDocument pdfdoc = new PdfDocument(writer1);
    PdfPage page = pdfdoc.AddNewPage(PageSize.A4);
    PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(page);
    Table TestTbl = MakeTable(28); // 28 Rows to push page 2
    iText.Layout.Renderer.TableRenderer RendererTbl = (iText.Layout.Renderer.TableRenderer)TestTbl.CreateRendererSubTree();
    Rectangle RectangleTbl = new Rectangle(14, 390 - 243, 567, 243);
    RendererTbl = addTableToPage(pdfdoc, 1, RectangleTbl, RendererTbl);
    while (RendererTbl != null)
    {
        page = pdfdoc.AddNewPage(A4);
        canvas = new PdfCanvas(page);
        RectangleTbl = new Rectangle(14, 675 - 661, 567, 661);
        RendererTbl = addTableToPage(pdfdoc, 2, RectangleTbl, RendererTbl);
    }
    return zMS;
}

public static Table MakeTable(int QtRows)
{
    PdfFont Font = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(iText.IO.Font.Constants.StandardFontFamilies.HELVETICA, "CP1252");
    float[] Cols = new float[] { 72, 128, 27, 16, 19, 16, 29, 40.5f, 33, 47, 36.5f, 31.5f, 31.5f, 22, 18 };
    Table MyTable = new Table(Cols);
    MyTable.SetWidth(Cols.Sum());
    MyTable.SetFixedLayout();
    for (var Row = 1; Row <= QtRows; Row++)
    {
        for (var Col = 1; Col <= Cols.Length - 1; Col++)
        {
            if (Col == 1)
            {
                Cell MyCell = new Cell().SetPadding(0.75f).SetMargin(0).SetHeight(7).Add(new Paragraph().SetFont(Font).SetFontSize(5).Add(Row.ToString()));
                MyTable.AddCell(MyCell);
            }
            else
            {
                Cell MyCell = new Cell().SetPadding(0.75f).SetMargin(0).SetHeight(7).Add(new Paragraph().SetFont(Font).SetFontSize(5).Add(Col.ToString()));
                MyTable.AddCell(MyCell);
            }
        }
    }
    return MyTable;
}

public static iText.Layout.Renderer.TableRenderer addTableToPage(PdfDocument pdfDocument, int pageNum, Rectangle rectangle, iText.Layout.Renderer.TableRenderer renderer)
{
    PdfPage page = pdfDocument.GetPage(pageNum);
    PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(page.NewContentStreamAfter(), page.GetResources(), pdfDocument);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(pdfCanvas, pdfDocument, rectangle);
    renderer.SetParent(canvas.GetRenderer());
    iText.Layout.Layout.LayoutResult layoutResult = renderer.Layout(new iText.Layout.Layout.LayoutContext(new iText.Layout.Layout.LayoutArea(pageNum, rectangle)));
    iText.Layout.Renderer.IRenderer rendererToAdd = layoutResult.GetStatus() == iText.Layout.Layout.LayoutResult.FULL ? renderer : layoutResult.GetSplitRenderer();
    // Below line causes Exception 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index
    // on AddChild every time rendererToAdd = layoutResult.GetSplitRenderer()
    canvas.GetRenderer().AddChild(rendererToAdd.SetParent(canvas.GetRenderer()));
    return layoutResult.GetStatus() != iText.Layout.Layout.LayoutResult.FULL ? (iText.Layout.Renderer.TableRenderer)layoutResult.GetOverflowRenderer() : null;
}
```

Comment: In the code you attached you were never adding cells into the table. I've fixed it in the code so that it reproduces the problem

Answer (score 0):

The exception occurs because you call `canvas.GetRenderer().AddChild(rendererToAdd.SetParent(canvas.GetRenderer()));` which layouts the child renderer before drawing it (i.e. roughly speaking add = layout + draw). However, table renderers are meant to be layouted only once. The exception could have been more verbose about it of course.

If you want to draw the table right away after it has been layouted, you can do so with `rendererToAdd.Draw(new DrawContext(pdfDocument, pdfCanvas));`

Additionally, you have to make sure the area on the canvas is initialized with `canvas.GetRenderer().GetCurrentArea();`.

The complete code of `addTableToPage` then becomes:

```
public static iText.Layout.Renderer.TableRenderer addTableToPage(PdfDocument pdfDocument, int pageNum, Rectangle rectangle, iText.Layout.Renderer.TableRenderer renderer)
{
    PdfPage page = pdfDocument.GetPage(pageNum);
    PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(page.NewContentStreamAfter(), page.GetResources(), pdfDocument);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(pdfCanvas, pdfDocument, rectangle);
    canvas.GetRenderer().GetCurrentArea();
    renderer.SetParent(canvas.GetRenderer());
    iText.Layout.Layout.LayoutResult layoutResult = renderer.Layout(new iText.Layout.Layout.LayoutContext(new iText.Layout.Layout.LayoutArea(pageNum, rectangle)));
    iText.Layout.Renderer.IRenderer rendererToAdd = layoutResult.GetStatus() == iText.Layout.Layout.LayoutResult.FULL ? renderer : layoutResult.GetSplitRenderer();
    rendererToAdd.Draw(new DrawContext(pdfDocument, pdfCanvas));
    return layoutResult.GetStatus() != iText.Layout.Layout.LayoutResult.FULL ? (iText.Layout.Renderer.TableRenderer)layoutResult.GetOverflowRenderer() : null;
}
```

**Another way** exists, however, and it looks much more straightforward to me. You can simply override the default `DocumentRenderer` and specify page areas you need. The rest of the layout will be done automatically.

Example of customized renderer:

```
private class CustomDocumentRenderer : DocumentRenderer
{
    public CustomDocumentRenderer(Document document) : base(document)
    {}

    protected internal override LayoutArea UpdateCurrentArea(LayoutResult overflowResult)
    {
        currentArea = (RootLayoutArea) base.UpdateCurrentArea(overflowResult);
        if (currentArea.pageNumber == 1)
        {
            currentArea.SetBBox(new Rectangle(14, 390 - 243, 567, 243));
        }
        else
        {
            currentArea.SetBBox(new Rectangle(14, 675 - 661, 567, 661));
        }

        return currentArea;
    }
}
```

The complete code now looks like following (you don't need to layout manually anymore):

```
Document document = new Document(pdfdoc);
document.SetRenderer(new CustomDocumentRenderer(document));

Table TestTbl = MakeTable(28); 
document.Add(TestTbl);
document.Close();
```